# Use Barman within a Docker swarm

Tags: postgresql, database-backups, docker-swarm, backup-strategies, barman

I'm almost new to the PostgreSQL technology but today, I have a Docker swarm with two nodes dedicated for the databases. Consider that the first node contains the "master" PostgreSQL (> 9.3) and the second one is just a replica of the master.

This backup method doesn't suit me anymore since my cluster could grow up soon and I would need point in time recovery. In did some research and that's why I would like to use Barman (http://www.pgbarman.org/).

I was wondering if Barman can be efficient in a Docker swarm and if some of you had a return of experience on it.

I'm trying at the moment to build this infrastructure. I'll post updates if needed.

Additionnaly, more documentation on the topic could help me :)

Thanks, Paul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some days practicing barman and reading the documentation, I think Barman is a suitable and really good option for backups in a Docker Swarm since it allows **streaming backup**.

You can choose to backup every minutes a small amount of data. It's light for Docker.
If there is a disaster and your PostgreSQL service comes down you can still recover from a recent backup.

Comment: You don’t need to backup every minute barman gets latest chunk of data from master postgres. You can schedule backup every night for example.  See barman cron manual to get a better picture

Comment: You can take a look into this project, it may help you: [https://github.com/paunin/PostDock](https://github.com/paunin/PostDock)